# Replace keys in template string with object properties

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object like this.

```
var obj = {Id:1,Rate:5,Price:200,Name:"History"}
```

And a template like this.

```
var templateString = '<option id="{Id}">{Name}</option>'
```

I want to replace the template values with object values. How can i do this. I am no expert of javascript regular expressions.

The desired output

```
var optionString = '<option id="1">History</option>'
```

### Fiddle Sample

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for http://handlebarsjs.com/?

Comment: No i dont want to use handlebarsjs

Comment: How was this voted "too broad" ? Seriously ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a callback :

```
var optionString = templateString.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(_,k){
      return obj[k];
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/tukec/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex, this can be done by finding all the properties of the object using `Object.keys` and then replace each of them by it's value.

Try like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  templateString = templateString.replace(`**${key}**`, `"${obj[key]}"`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this will work for you if it has just one occurrence

```
var optionString = templateString.replace('{Id}',obj.Id).replace('{Name}',obj.Name)
```

Comment: I need dynamic template and can't define name and id in replace function